# How to make user admin in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I want**

I'm making a project in **laravel 5.7** and I need to make a user admin and I have no separate form for this and I have only 1 migration as `users`, how can I implement that one can become admin?

**I did**

I have made a condition in `user migration` that if user have `id == 1` then update `is_admin = 1` but there's a flaw that if the I have much traffic on my site, then if I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` and after refreshing the database, if a user will register before registering me then he will become admin, that's what I don't need.

Comment: directly set the is_admin value to 1 for you and for rest set it 0 as default.

Comment: make seeder class for that particular admin user.

Comment: "*if a user will register before registering me then he will become admin, that's what I don't need*" conflicts with "*How to make first user automatically admin*". Of course he will, he was the first user to register.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya can you make a code for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To continue with Ali Ozen's answer, after following those steps...
Create a seeder using `php artisan make:seeder UserSeeder`

in seeder file, add below

```
use App\User;

User::create(['name' => 'Admin', 'email' => 'admin@example.com', 'password' => bcrypt('password'), 'is_admin' => 1]);
```

Add **UserSeeder::class** to DatabaseSeeder.php

Then run the migration using

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

To refresh run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: @InYourFace I would be careful of using seeder in this case. If your code base is exposed. Your username and password be known to others. You also have to be careful when running those commands because `refresh` will clean up your database and re-run the migration.

Answer (score 4):

```
php artisan make:migration add_is_admin_to_users_table --table="users"
```

after that open the newest migration file. In the function up function

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
    });
```

Write this. Then run the php artisan migrate. 
Thats it. You don't need the refresh.